# RoR: concatenate two variables and passing parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, concatenation

How do I concatenate variables in Ruby on Rails?

Say I have this:

```
        tags.each do |tag, index|
            @tag_index = client.tag_recent_media(tag)
        end
```

I'm not sure how to put `tag` and `index` together? And does it make sense that I want to pass the parameter `tag` into `tag_recent_media`?

Thanks

EDIT

I applied the answer below:

```
    @tag.concat(index.to_s) = client.tag_recent_media(tag)
```

I get a syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
                @tag.concat(index.to_s) = client.tag_recent_media(tag)
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm iterating through `tags` and I'm trying to apply the `index` position of the tag onto the `tag` value and then using that as a variable.

so if the first value that it iterates is positioned 0 and is valued "apple" then I'd like to have the variable

```
@apple_0 = client.tag_recent_media()
```

Also the `tag_recent_media()` is supposed to be instance methods from an API I'm using. The [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/instagram/0.10.0/Instagram/Client/Tags) shows that its supposed to pass a string.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here.  What is the desired output?

Comment: @MarkRushakoff I updated my question, hopefully it makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation of strings can be done using [concat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) method:

For example:

In your case I am assuming you have `tag` as `string` type and `index` as `integer` type. So you can do as follows:

```
 a="tag"; b=1
 a.concat(b.to_s)  #=> "tag1"
```

You are not clearly indicated what does your `tag_recent_media` is doing. If you give more info about the method you are calling it will be easy to help with correct answer.

Comment: I updated my question with your solution, but having problems and I discussed what `tag_recent_media` does. Hopefully this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do is I'm iterating through tags and I'm trying to apply the index position of the tag onto the tag value and then using that as a variable.
>
> so if the first value that it iterates is positioned 0 and is valued "apple" then I'd like to have the variable

```
@apple_0 = client.tag_recent_media()
```

---

That will require metaprogramming with defining dynamic method and it's really bad approach in this case. Why the array is not enough for you?

```
@new_tags = []
tags.each do |tag, index|
  @new_tags[index] = client.tag_recent_media(tag)
end
```

Or even better

```
@new_tags = []
tags.each_with_index.map {|tag, i| @new_tags[i] = client.tag_recent_media(tag) }
```

Then you can iterate through @new_tag array.